# Where is "Custom Attribute 14" in AD Schema?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, schema

I'm getting the following error when writing to Active Directory attribute 14

> 00002082: AtrErr: DSID-03151314, #1:  0: 00002082: DSID-03151314,
>   problem 1005 (CONSTRAINT_ATT_TYPE), data 0, Att 2025a
>   (extensionAttribute14):len 34686

My guess is that I'm writing a string that is too long for the attribute.   I also think that rangeUpper is the LDAP property that controls how large a value can be placed in AD.

I've now hit a wall and can't locate Custom Attribute 14 in the adsiedit.msc.  Can anyone tell me where this is located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CN=ms-Exch-Extension-Attribute-14,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=example,DC=com`

Its `rangeUpper` is 2048.

See MSDN for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms980479(v=exchg.65).aspx